# Serving Angular app using Django

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have a DjangoREST-Nginx-Gunicorn build, and I am using angular as the frontend.

This is the first time I work with this stack together, although I'm very familiar with Django.
From what I'm used to, I'm serving pages using `render` with django templating.

Since I am using REST and angular, the project build is kind of different and I wonder how should I serve the angular app through this stack.

This is my project build

```
├── client
│   ├── client-app
│   └── index.html
├── gunicorn_start.sh
├── run
│   └── gunicorn.sock
└── server
    ├── config
    ├── __init__
    ├── manage.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── static
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

What I wish to do, is to serve `client/index.html` and let the angular app handle everything from there on.

What would be the right way to do so?

EDIT:
I have in `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'client/index.html')
```

But I get an exception

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is not being found either because `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is not set, or because your template isn't inside an `app/templates` folder, where `app` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` (and you have `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` in `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`).

ps: if you're not doing anything in your view, i.e. just rendering the template

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'client/index.html')
```

then you can do it in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='client/index.html'))
```

(or maybe you just spelled `/` wrong? it should be `^$`...)

Comment: as you can see there is no templates folder... So how should I go about this? I really don't want to have a `template/client` folder inside of client folder

Comment: I thought you said you were very familiar with Django...?  If you don't want Django to find your template in your app, then list its folder in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.  Perhaps a better question.. why do you want Django involved in serving a static html page?  It seems very inefficient.

Comment: If i include it in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` I have to stick to the `client/templates/client` structure which I want to avoid. Eventually I passed this idea, I'm going to store the angular app on aws S3

Comment: That's not true at all. You can add only the directory containing the template to `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, and it can be anywhere on your file system.

Answer (score 1):

when domain entered you should redirect the user to client/index.html and then using angular-router you can do pretty much everything you have done using php or django routes
[for more info about angular routing](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)

Comment: Can't see how to get this through, I've created a views files under server, created routing from `urls` to a view in `views` and in the view I wrote `render(request, 'client/index.html')` and it doesn't work

Comment: put you'r index.html file in you'r root file in server it will render by default if you'r using apache based servers

Comment: I'm not going to do that, the index html is part of the client folder which has a lot of relative routing.
I am getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error

Comment: ../client/index.html i guess should work if not i don't know bro